# Get an error when loading GLTF file on React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, gltf

I'm created component for loading and displaying scene with 3D-model. When I'm trying to load GTLF object using `GLTFLoader`, I getting an error like this:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr5qP.png)

#### Code of loading GLTF-file:

```js
setObj = () => {
        this.loader = new GLTFLoader();
        this.loader.load(obj, gltf => {
            this.mesh = gltf.scene;
            this.mesh.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
            this.mesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            this.mesh.position.set(0, -100, 0);
            this.scene.add(this.mesh);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the `glTF` asset in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes, sure. [Link](https://github.com/CreativeRusBear/Three.js/tree/master/src/projects/Man/model)

Comment: The model loads fine when I drag'n'drop it into the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/). So it's not an issue with the asset or with `GLTFLoader`. Can you please check if there are no 404 errors in your browser console/network tab when loading the asset in your application?

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes, but I have 304 error instead of 404. And it links on `http://localhost:3000/static/media/textures/Material_0.001_baseColor.jpeg`.